# Cannot reload AVD list error in intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I keep getting this error from Intelliji 15.0.3. I run the android emulator and get the error and it keeps popping up. Not sure how to fix this. I got this after I installed the newest Android SDK. It happens on my android studio as well